# Vue Apollo refetch query on event

Tags: typescript, vue.js, graphql, apollo, vue-apollo

I have a query in my Component instance:

```
@Component({
  apollo: {
    cartProducts: {
      query: GET_CART_PRODUCTS,
      loadingKey: "loading",
    },
  }
})
```

It's loading my data correctly. Then I change data in my DB and want to refetch them on click, which call that function:

```
  refresh() {
    this.$apollo
      .query({
        query: GET_CART_PRODUCTS,
      })
      .then((res: any) => (this.cartProducts = res.data.cartProducts))
      .catch((err: any) => console.log(err));
  }
```

But it doesn't update `cartProducts` property, and doesn't give me any error. Although If I refresh my page new data are there. In my Apollo config I have such property `fetchPolicy: "network-only"`. What could be the reson of such behaviour? Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is quite simple, sorry to bother, I had to google it more.

```
   this.$apollo.queries.cartProducts.refetch()
```